# php vs regex for counting data

Tags: php, regex

i have an array, it have same data:

```
  data range    
115X0101-115X0200
115X0101-115X0200
115X0101-115X0200
```

the 115x mean production code..this unimportant.
we just concern at four digits behind it that we can counting.

```
1. i want script read or search "0101" and "0200" from 115X0101-115X0200
2. i have tried using regex to count them become 200-101=100
3. the "115X0101-115X0200" repeated until there are 20 data like this
4. after it reached 20, show result at page:
           data range
             100
```

Comment: How is this related to MySQL? Do you have any tables that are relevant here?

Comment: Sorry, but that makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: That doesn't look like any date format I've ever seen.  Can you explain how those are dates?  Can you give us your reasoning behind the math operations you want to perform?  *What are you actually trying to accomplish?*

Comment: This does not make any sense at all. Please explain what you are trying to do and use intelligible english.

Comment: I assume "date" == "data". Otherwise I concur, this doesn't make a whole lot of sense yet.

Comment: Want to help as well but question makes no sense alright...

Comment: i have changed my question..sorry if any mistake.

Comment: Fixing the typo unfortunately didn't make the question any clearer. For starters, can you explain what the different parts of `115X0101-115X0200` are supposed to mean?

Comment: @deceze: i have explained the question

Comment: I still don't see any logic. `115X0101-115X0200` means `0101-0200`, which means `200-101=100`, where `101` means `1-1=0`? Sorry, but that part makes no sense without further explanation.

Comment: Can you describe the steps, in English, not code, what you want to do to these numbers? What are the possible inputs these steps need to work on, i.e. could `115X0101-115X0200` be in any other possible format, like `115X231+115X853`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the raw data, the easiest way to extract it is probably using a regular expression, as you've mentioned.

You'll probably want something like this (in PHP):

```
# Get this from the database
$sql_results = array(
    '115X0101-115X0200',
    '115X0101-115X0200',
    '115X0101-115X0200',
);

foreach($sql_results as $row)
{
    preg_match_all('/\d{4}/', $row, $matches);
                #200                     #101
    echo intval($matches[0][1]) - intval($matches[0][0]) + 1;
}
```

For each row, preg_match will find groups of 4 digits (`\d{4}`) and place them in `$matches` (use `var_dump($matches)` to see what it looks like).

#### More on Regex

- [Regular Expressions Cheatsheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/)
- [Regular Expressions Help](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

#### SQL Limit

Side note:  If you only want 20 results at a time, you'll want to `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 20` when you query the database.  To get rows 31-50 you'd use `LIMIT 30, 20`, which means offset by 30, then get 20 rows.